# Use map or dictionary to find value

Tags: shell

Here is my situation.  I have an array of Device id's.  I know which device id's go with which ip addresses.  I want to use the device id's to find the correct ip address and pass both of them in a command.  I am using a shell script to do this.

Here is some psuedo code for what I want.

This is my dictionary type thing matching id's with ip's, no particular order

```
 dictionary_thing = ( id:ip
                      id:ip
                      id:ip
                      id:ip )
```

This is my array of id that I am using in no particular order

```
 array_of_used_ids = ( id
                       id
                       id )
```

Maybe make an array of objects with two properties (id and ip) for each id found

```
 array_object
 for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
 {
      array_object[i]= new object and set id to dictionary_thing id and ip
 }
```

then I want to run all the commands in a for loop (or whatever you suggest)

```
 for id in array_of_used_ids
    ./run_this_command with 

 for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
 {
      ./command array_object[i].ip array_object[i].id
 }
```

Comment: what OS and shell flavour?

Comment: Mac and 3.2.48(1)-release.  Is that what you meant with flavor?

Comment: by shell flavour i mean one of `bash`, `ksh`, `tcsh` etc

Comment: bash version 4 has associative arrays, which would simplify things. Any possibility of upgrading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have your primary arrays built, so build a regex from the used IDs

```
regex="^${array_of_used_ids[0]}:"
i=1
while [ $i -lt ${#array_of_used_ids[*]} ]; do
 regex="$regex|^${array_of_used_ids[$i]}:"
 i=$(( $i + 1))
done
```

This should give you a regex like "^id:|^id:|^id:"
Then iterate your dictionary checking each against the regex, when matched, replace the separating ':' with a space

```
array_object=()
i=0
j=0
while [ $i -lt ${#dictionary_thing[*]} ]; do
 if [[ $dictionary_thing[$i] =~ $regex ]]; then 
   array_object[$j] = ${dictionary_thing[$i]/:/ } #if it is possible for an ID to contain a ':', you will need a different method for splitting here
   j=$(( $j + 1 ))
 fi
 i=$(( $i + 1 ))
done
```

Finally, iterate your result object and execute the command

```
i=0
while [ $i -lt ${#array_object[*]} ]; do
 command_to_execute ${array_object[$i]}
 i=$(( $i + 1 ))
done
```

Comment: In hindsight, I suppose you could just execute the commmand in the second loop there, eliminating the need for array_object and the third loop.